# Trigger controller action on every model create/update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, sinatra, sequel

Syntax below is Sinatra, but question applies to Rails too.

Multiple models use the `after_update` and `after_create` hooks.

```
class MyModel < Sequel::Model
  include ActivityStreams

def after_create
  send_to_event_stream_after_create
end

def after_update
  send_to_event_stream_after_update
end
```

The methods `send_to_event_steam_*` are defined in the `ActivityStreams` module.

It seems like the act of firing events off to an event stream should be a Controller responsibility. This action occurs when various models are created/updated and there is no real domain-specific behaviour that distinguishes what happens when ModelA or ModelB is updated/created.

I'd like to DRY the repeated calls to `send_to_event_steam_*` that are currently littered across almost all models just because the create & update hooks are available in models.

Is this refactoring even possible? Is the use of `Observable` the only way?

Comment: My first thought is to make a module with those hooks and include it in the models as needed.

Comment: If you want this to happen in the controller, then the obvious question is, what is it in the controller code that is updating the models?